# How to save state when back button pressed

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an android quiz application, 
now each time a user answers wrong, a freezing timer show up, the user must wait until he will be able to answer again, my problem is as follow:

Each time the user answers wrong and the timer shows up, he can run away by pressing back button to main menu and then press the question button to restart the whole thing.

I need help with us `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` functions.

Code is:

```
public class Questionsctivity extends Activity {

    List<Question> quesList;
    int score = 0;
    int qid = 0;
    Question currentQ;
    TextView txtQuestion,clockView;
    RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
    Button butNext;
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questionsctivity);

        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        quesList = db.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        clockView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView222);
        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        rda = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);

        butNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

        setQuestionView();

        butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER() + " " + answer.getText());
                if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())) {//bad equal to
                    score++;
                    Log.d("Good Answer", "Your Score" + score);
                } else {
                    Log.d("bad Answer", "Your Score" + score);

                    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            clockView.setText("Wrong Answer +" +
                                    "seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                            butNext.setEnabled(false);
                            txtQuestion.setEnabled(false);
                            rda.setEnabled(false);
                            rdb.setEnabled(false);
                            rdc.setEnabled(false);

                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            clockView.setText("Continue Answering!");
                            butNext.setEnabled(true);
                            txtQuestion.setEnabled(true);
                            rda.setEnabled(true);
                            rdb.setEnabled(true);
                            rdc.setEnabled(true);
                        }

                    }.start();
                }
                if (qid < 7) {
                    currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Questionsctivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }




    private void setQuestionView() {
        txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
        rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
        rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
        qid++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Questionsctivity Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.ourapp.myapplication/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();


        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Questionsctivity Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.ourapp.myapplication/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `onPause()` method to save the state of the Activity since the `onSaveInstanceState()` will only be called in case if the system is going to destroy the Activity (in case if memory needs to be freed). The `onSaveInstanceState()` will not be called if a user presses the back (or home) button to close the current Activity.

You may persist the current state in the shared preferences or local database for example.

Then you can restore the saved state in the `onResume()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You could just manually call the `onSaveInstanceState` with a manually created `Bundle`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(key, value);
    onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    super.onBackPressed(); //Check if you still want to go back
}
```

Comment: Getting `IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` with this approach

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to disable back button or use according to your requirement.

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    // use your own custom method or you can remove super.onBackPressed(); to disable back button.
    }
```

Comment: thank, im not looking for disabling the back button, i just want to be able to save the content (or the state of the activity) so when a user will press back button and return to question activity, state will be resumed as before.

Comment: What you actually want, it's not clear. so if the user goes back and again press question button then it shouldn't start from the first?

Comment: no, for that i have a "new game" option, so i want the user to be able to press back button and the again go to question activity and the state will stay the same, means, if he now in question 3 of 10, he will be able to return to the same state, for that i have the variable "qid" that tells the question id

Comment: one simple thing you can do is you can take a boolean in your database for the user and when ever is answered marked true and if its not the mark false. Initially all will be marked false. so when next time the data is fetched, fetch those data that is marked false. so thus you will be able to get the unanswered questions.

Comment: you sure its the simplest way? i thought about onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState  functions in order to save the state

Comment: yes, because if your application is closed or the phone is restarted then you wont able to track if you dont save in your database. so as per my option you should keep a track so, if user closed the app and starts again he will start from the question that he haven't answered.

Comment: mm sounds like a nice and suitable idea, ill try it, thanks!

Comment: @OzGiat You need to add your code in `onBackPressed()` section .